# Select anchor inside div with jquery using "this"?

Tags: jquery, anchor

If you have

```
<div class="expFold" id="i_0"><a href="#">▼</a></div>
```

and

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

in your click function gives you "i_0", how do you target the text within the anchor using

```
$(this)
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

use `.text()`:

```
$(this).find('a').text();
```

or

```
$("a", this).text();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R5Lrw/1/)**

**To set the value:**

```
$("a", this).text('test');
```

or

```
$(this).find('a').text('test');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R5Lrw/2/)**

Comment: Or `$("a", this).text()`

Comment: Sorry - I may have worded my question incorrectly. I'd like to change the text inside the anchor. $(this).find(a).text("test"); isn't doing it (I'm obviously using it wrong). Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: I think you need to put quotes around `a`: `$(this).find('a').text("test");`

Comment: Wow - thanks Milind and Max. I hadn't finsihed editing my original question, and you'd already posted an answer!